# SCCM 2012 R2 Task Sequence fails with error 0x80070032

Tags: virtual-machine, logging, esxi, winpe, sccm

I'm trying to capture an image for using in SCCM 2012 R2 to deploy computers in my organization. I have a build and capture task sequence set up and deployed it to my unknown computers. When I try this task sequence with booting a virtual machine, I get error 0x80070032 after a while in the proces. Here is a link to the smsts.log:

[enter link description here](http://student.howest.be/sylvain.vansteelandt/logs/smsts.log)